# Ручная обработка столкновений unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

В unity есть стандартная физика - на основе компонентов rigidbody и collider'ов.
При автоматическом расчете скорость объектов меняется. А мне нужно чтобы модуль скорости был одним и тем же, а менялось только направление (в зависимости от условий).
Как вручную менять направление после столкновения?

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    fallVector = GetRigidbody.velocity.normalized;
    fallNormalVector = collision.contacts[0].normal;

    var reflectedVelocity = Vector3.Reflect(fallVector, fallNormalVector).normalized;
    GetRigidbody.velocity = reflectedVelocity * 3;        
}
```

При подобной обработке срабатывает и стандартное изменение направления, и то что написано вручную, в итоге - неадекватно работает.

Просьба не предлагать использовать триггеры вместо коллайдеров, или объяснить тогда, как рассчитать траекторию отражения от триггера т.к. в событии OnTriggerEnter2D() нет переменной Collision2D из которой можно получить нормаль в точке столкновения.

Comment: направление меняется путем умножения координаты по нужной  оси на `-1`. При этом угол отскока будет таким же как угол до столкновения.

Comment: Это только при столкновении со строго вертикальной или горизонтальной стеной. Неужели нет более простого способа, чтобы не рассчитывать всю геометрию вручную, после OnTriggerEnter2D

Comment: всмысле? что так сложно взять формулу отскока от наклонной поверхности и применить её? А угол можно вычислять за счет бросания какого-нибудь raycast или linecast в сторону движения и при пересечении оного с предметом коллизии расчитывать его. ведь у объекта столкновения взять направление оси вполне можно

Comment: С формулами проблем нет, вопросы только по тех. части - как узнать наклон стороны коллайдера, с касанием о который произошло событие? raycast не обязан попадать в точку соприкосновения коллайдеров(триггеров) т.к. его наверно нужно кидать из центра - соответственно он может вообще не попасть на объект столкновения, или попасть под другим углом. Как тогда быть?

Comment: `т.к. его наверно нужно кидать из центра` - что мешает кидать несколько лучей  распределенных по ширине объекта? ....... `может вообще не попасть на объект столкновения` - ну значит впереди коллайдера нет. в чём проблема? не ясно........ `попасть под другим углом` - под каким другим углом? ты определяешь есть ли впереди нужный объект для столкновения, и если да, берешь его оси и оси объекта и рассчитываешь угол.......кстати, вообще зачем используется `Rigidbody` и физика? она имеет значение? если Vector3.Reflect использовать оно будет работать нормально